# Coonect storybored to xib

Tags: xcode

I have a project with a xib but I want to add a storyboard and link the xib to it .
How can i do it
**My aim**
When I click on a button on the xib I want it to go to a view controller on the storyboard  file.
Please answer in steps 
Thanks for any help

This is critical

I am using XCODE 5.1.1

And IOS 7.1

And OSX mavericks

Comment: You can instantiate the second viewcontroller from storyboard and navigate to it in button action method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that your .xib file does not contain a View Controller (otherwise you could place that controller in the Storyboard), but contains a simple View (`UIView`, `UITableViewCell`, etc).

It is likely that this view belongs to a View Controller that you added to the Storyboard. If this is the case, your view could either:

- call a delegate method, while the parent view controller implements that method, or
- post a notification, while the parent view controller handles the notification

If you need to switch views, probably you want to perform a segue. So you'll need to perform it inside the delegate method or the notification handler.